# openshift UID permissions for files different on deployment than pod 3.11

Tags: openshift

curious if anyone can explain this one to me, I'm using ocp 3.11 and NFS as the  persistence for my containers...

if I run the container as a Deployment I end up with what looks like the correct permissions (e.g. arbitrary UID):

drwx------. 20 1000060000 nfsnobody 4096 Nov  5 10:29 alpha

however, if I run the same container as a simple pod I end up with the USER as owning the files:

drwxr-x---.  3         26        26   41 Nov  5 11:29 lastone

i would have thought the pod would write with the same UID as the deployment above.  I'm probably missing something simple here and any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: What service account and security context constraint do each run under. The latter looks like it is running with permissions to run as any user ID, and thus is using what the image says to run as, rather than be forced to run as project user ID.

Comment: Some related information in https://cookbook.openshift.org/users-and-role-based-access-control/how-can-i-enable-an-image-to-run-as-a-set-user-id.html

Comment: this is a good tip, I've done some testing of this by printing the scc that gets assigned when I specify no service account but only take whatever the defafult is:  for the deployment I get            "openshift.io/scc": "restricted" but for the pod I get "openshift.io/scc": "anyuid"...I'm still unclear why those are different when running the same image as a pod and as a deployment but will keep digging.

Comment: I found that the user I was running in had cluster-admin granted to it, when I remove cluster-admin, the pod runs with 'restricted' scc.